# Open an external website on Google Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

So, I am trying to get a handle with Google Chrome Extensions.

I've already done 50% of the script, but I stopped at one step:

How can I load an external website - for example: www.mysite.com/page.php - at the popup.html?

I only had success when I used iFrame, but, it's ugly and insecure... :(

Is there some way to do it with jquery (ajax)?

Thanks in advance.

---

So, this is how my manifest.json is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "XCLickF",
  "description": "X file",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": { "scripts": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js","background.js"] },

  "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_title": "XMail",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

And how my background.js is:

```
function poll() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; // Implemented elsewhere.
    xhr.open("GET", 'http://disqus.com/', false);
    xhr.send(null);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}

function handleStateChange() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        updateUi(resp);
    }
}

function updateUi(json) {
    console.log("JSON: ", json);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In order to solicit better questions, please post your code efforts so far.  You'll find the community is much more responsive when you show your work.

Comment: Thank you David! I'm in love with this community. :) I'll post it

Comment: What data do you need to get from the server, do you have access to the server? or are you loading data from a server you can't control. The reason I ask is if you can format the data as JSONP or even encode  the data a JS variable?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can get all html of that page with jquery ajax (or xhr). After getting html, you must style/execute js'. And also you can redirect to your webpage (but mostly it can get ban from google store) You cannot show page without using iframe.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'www.google.com',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); // data gives all of html
  }
});
```

Also you can cross-domain free iframe plugins that maybe helps your work.

[Iframe Height Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/Sly777/Iframe-Height-Jquery-Plugin)

[Iframe Resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)

Comment: Your code below returns `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www... 
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` So your answer may be valid if a header is present that allows [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: ı was thinking you want to use for your websites. I mean you will allow cors for your app. But offcourse, you will get error when you get any websites that you don't add cors.

Comment: Ok so in this case (scraping an external website) using an ajax request will not work. 
Regarding your other solution using iframe height plugin: As far as i understood [your tutorial](https://github.com/Sly777/Iframe-Height-Jquery-Plugin) it can not be used on local pages: `You shouldn't use it on local because it does not work correctly in chrome (chrome gives cross domain error on local) `. This seems to me that this suggestion does not help either. It is not clear to me how you incorporated the chrome extension part of the question into your answer.